# Terminology: Long press or Touch & hold?

Tags: user-expectation, interface, terminology

I've seen both versions used in Android. What do you think is the best term to use? I've also heard people to use "Long click", "Long touch" & "Long tap" but I personally don't like any of those. It would be nice to finally get some standard for this terminology.

Comment: For my opinion "Touch & hold", because it explains user action in details.

Comment: I don't have any evidence or data to back me up so I'm going to add it as a comment, I'd say "Touch and hold" or "Press and hold" describes the action which is required to complete the task more precisely, so I'd go with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if this is for Android, chances are you're using Material, and according to [**Material Design guidelines**](https://material.google.com/patterns/gestures.html#gestures-touch-mechanics), the proper term is *long press*

[image]

Comment: +1 for linking to a reference, although I still prefer "press and hold"

Comment: I also prefer to use the term "Press and hold". Se my answer below.

Comment: The Material Design Guidelines are a tool meant for developers. While the documentation does deal with UX, I don't think the terminology used within is necessarily reflective of what *should* be displayed to a user. Excluding, of course, the [section specifically detailing writing best practices](https://material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles).

Comment: +1 Apple also calls it long press. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture

Comment: link to Material docs is dead, but in the [current version](https://material.io/design/interaction/gestures.html#types-of-gestures) terminology remains the same

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest "Touch and hold". Many users tend not to understand the term "long" in longpress. Therefore "Press and [then] hold" is a better description of the action.

---

#### Edit

OK, due to the comments below, here is a more descriptive answer :-)

"Longpress" means "press for a long time".The word "long" comes first but that is the second action the user has to commit. We also have to tell the user how much time (s)he shall spend during that "long" time.

The word "longpress" is not (yet) a term that common people understand.

So, every term beginning with the word "long..." aught to be avoided.

"Press and hold" on the other hand tells the user to 1: press on the item and then 2: keep on doing so until something else happens, something that will inform the user (s)he can release his/her finger from the device.

Comment: Can you add references to back this up? There are many assumptions in the answer that have my doubt. Long is an adjective that announces how to press, I don't understand why people won't read it that way. "Touch and hold" can be interpreted as separate instructions, where "touch" suggests to touch and release before the "hold" instruction comes into the short term memory. I don't say this is true, but there might be more to it than what you put forward.